# to change the drawable right of an edit text

Tags: android, onclick, android-drawable

I'm trying to change the drawable in my EditText as it is in the image.[image: Please refer to the password column][image]

I'm using the following code to make the drawable clickable.

```
 password_editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
                final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
                final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= (password_editText.getRight() - password_editText
                            .getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds()
                            .width())) {
                        // your action here
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "drawable click",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

In this I would like to change the drawable in the password column to be changed on clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You can change drawable at runtime using

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.your_drawable );

password_editText.setCompoundDrawables( null, null, img, null );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds function:

```
password_editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.yourdrawable, 0);
```

The order of params : left, top, right, bottom